# Ping Device Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a program that will ping a device 375 times to see if it is connected to my network.

The reason why it does so many pings is because when the device is in low power mode it only wakes after several minutes to check in.

Waiting for 375 pings to get a response is too time consuming. Is there a way to modify this code to immediately stop and move to the print statement as soon as it gets a valid response instead of waiting for all 375 pings to analyze the results??

```
    device_ip = "192.168.2.235"  
try:
    result = subprocess.check_output(["ping", "-n", "375", device_ip])
    time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M")

    if (bytes("Reply from " + device_ip, 'utf-8')) in result:  
       print("device found")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
device_ip = "192.168.2.235"
while true; do ping -c1 device_ip > /dev/null && break; done
```

It will ping until a response is received which is simpler and cleaner